# XSLT - get sorted information extract from cdata

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I’m new in the xslt topic and have a problem that can't solve on my own.
Here e excample of my xml file:

```
<node>
  <failure><![CDATA[
    some useless information.
    CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 not defined.
    CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833 not possible.
    CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 not defined. 
    some useless information.]]>
  </failure>
</node>
```

The main problem is that the information stand in a CDATA block and many different informations are mixed up. I have found a way to get them out, but only as a string value not able to differentiate between the sort.

I need a way to extract elements that fit the pattern: "CRS [-unknown-] [id] not [result]"

What i want is something like this:

```
<failure>
    <CRS>
      <id> urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 </id>
      <result> not defined </result>
    </CRS>
    <CRS>
      <id> urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833 </id>
      <result> not posible </result>
    </CRS>
    <CRS>
      <id> urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 </id>
      <result> not defined </result>
    </CRS>
</failure>
```

Can somebody help me or made experience with simular problems?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  This will be _much_ easier in 2.0.

Comment: Sorry i forget that information. up to now i use XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 2.0 has `xsl:analyze-string` which is designed for precisely this task, so if at all possible I suggest you upgrade to a 2.0 processor such as [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml):

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <failure>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="failure"
         regex="^\s*CRS\s*(\S+)\s*(not\s*.*)$" flags="m">
      <xsl:matching-substring>
        <CRS>
          <id><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" /></id>
          <result><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(regex-group(2))" /></result>
        </CRS>
      </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
  </failure>
</xsl:template>
```

String manipulation facilities in XSLT 1.0 are extremely limited in comparison, and since XSLT is a functional language without updateable variables you'd have to write some sort of hideously complex set of recursive `call-template` logic to split up the text into separate lines and then extract the relevant bits out of each line in turn using `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

```
<xsl:template name="each-line">
  <xsl:param name="val" />
  <!-- pull out everything before the first newline and normalize (trim leading
       and trailing whitespace and squash internal whitespace to a single space
       character -->
  <xsl:variable name="firstLine"
    select="normalize-space(substring-before($val, '&#10;'))" />
  <!-- pull out everything after the first newline -->
  <xsl:variable name="rest" select="substring-after($val, '&#10;')" />
  <xsl:if test="$firstLine">
    <xsl:call-template name="process-line">
      <xsl:with-param name="line" select="$firstLine" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
  <!-- if there are still some non-empty lines left then process them recursively -->
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space($rest)">
    <xsl:call-template name="each-line">
      <xsl:with-param name="val" select="$rest" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-line">
  <xsl:param name="line" />
  <xsl:if test="starts-with($line, 'CRS ') and contains($line, ' not ')">
    <!-- here $line will be something like
         "CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 not defined." -->
    <CRS>
      <!-- ID is everything between the first and second spaces -->
      <id><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($line, ' '), ' ')" /></id>
      <!-- result is everything after the second space -->
      <result><xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-after($line, ' '), ' ')" /></result>
    </CRS>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

You would call this logic using a construct like

```
<xsl:template match="node">
  <failure>
    <xsl:call-template name="each-line">
      <xsl:with-param name="val" select="failure" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </failure>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The problem is that i need the transformation work in a normal browser and so i'm limitated to xslt 1.0, or not?

Comment: @Logi for browser use there's [Saxon CE](http://www.saxonica.com/ce/index.xml), which is an XSLT 2.0 processor implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: This might be a solution. But i want others have the possibility to use the files on their systems. Is there no solution for xslt 1.0?

Comment: @Logi I've added an example of the sort of recursive template you'd need to do this in pure XSLT 1.0

Comment: fine this is almost working.but the output is looking a bit strange.

some useless information.CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 not defined.CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833 not possible.
CRS urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25830 not defined.some useless information."

The <CRS> <id> and <result> tags are missing and i cant figute out the reason from the code.

Comment: @Logi I've added an example of how you might call the `each-line` template, does that make any more sense?